# magento 1.9.1.1 show multiple products with custom options on product page and be able to select them and add them all or some to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, custom-options, addtocart

magento 1.9.1.1 show multiple products with custom options on product page and be able to select them and add them all or some to cart

for example, I want a product page to show one main product, bundle prod, and then add multiple other products on the same page, all, or a few of them with custom options, and be able to select and add them to the cart, so also price on product page is updated based on selection

Some of the additional product will have data dropboxes, others a click box and some additional products will have their own custom options

Anyone any idea ? or knows a good extension for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "Related Products" feature, but unfortunately it does not allow custom options by default.

If the related products have custom options one would add them to the cart without custom options and then edit them from the cart page one by one to select the custom options. This is not the best user experience.

So to be able to select custom options for the related products, you would have to do some modifications:

- include form for custom options in the block that displays the related products, but use different field names for each, which include the product id
- change add to cart action where the related products are added (see [Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L220) so that these form values are used to customize each cart item.